# Customize XML for setting Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-preferences

I need to customize my layout which is `root_preferences`.
for instance: set gravity for SwitchPreferenceCompat or EditTextPreference.
It is the first time that I use setting fragment and I think both `settingFragment` and `root_Perfenses` are not like ordinary fragments, I can't give it Id, I can't set gravity.

My settingFragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import com.example.holyquran.R

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

My layout:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/messages_header">

    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="signature"
        app:title="نام صندوق"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="reply"
        app:entries="@array/reply_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/reply_values"
        app:key="reply"
        app:title="@string/reply_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory app:title="عمومی">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="sync"
        app:title="لرزش" />

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:dependency="sync"
        app:key="attachment"
        app:summaryOff="@string/attachment_summary_off"
        app:summaryOn="@string/attachment_summary_on"
        app:title="@string/attachment_title" />

</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    app:icon="@drawable/setting"
    app:title="settings">
    <SeekBarPreference
        android:key="volume_notifications"
        app:defaultValue="50"
        app:showSeekBarValue="true"
        app:title="volume" />
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="notifications"
        app:title="Disable notifications"
        android:summaryOff="Yow will no longer receive notifications"
        android:summaryOn="Yow will receive all notifications"/>
```

Now I want to set gravity of `<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/messages_header">` to center, I know it is not common to do this.

One more thing how can I use `sharePerference` in the Setting fragment?
I want to add a ***SeekBarPreference*** and my users can change the size of the application's text by moving it
[something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Lzn.png)

And last but not the least:
My app has vibration and there is a toggle in setting which is "لرزش", when it is on vibration is enabled otherwise it is diable so how to say if switch is on it is enabled else it is disabled?

As I said before, I do not have any experience with Setting fragment because I wasn't supposed to do it It was my workaholic job

[Here is the link of Project](https://github.com/AmirAndroidDeveloper/Holy-Quran) and setting folder is in ui folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I want to set gravity of `<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/messages_header">` to center, I know it is not common to do this.

Do do this you need to create a custom layout that has a `TextView` for the title with an id of `title` and normally set the gravity with `android:gravity`. Also you can use other `TextView` attributes that you can't use within the preference xml

For example:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

To apply that to the `PreferenceCategory` use `android:layout` attribute:

Assuming the layout you created for the title is `preference_message_header_title.xml`:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preference_message_header_title"
    android:title="@string/messages_header">
```

> One more thing how can I use sharePerfenses in the Setting fragment? I want to add a SeekBarPreference and my users can change the size of the application's text by moving it.

> and last but not the least: My app has vibration and there is a toggle in setting which is "لرزش", when it is on vibration is enabled otherwise it is diable so how to say if switch is on it is enabled else it is disabled?

These two requests quite abroad, but the general idea is that you attach a preference key in the preference XML using `android:key` like you already did with some preferences.

And in the settings fragment class you call `findPreference(myPreferenceKey)` to get the preference associated with that key, and `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` on it so that you can listen to the changes done by the user on that preference; then within the listener callback apply that normally by changing the corresponding `SharedPreference` value that you used to track the text size or the vibration status.